# Mock fs module using mockery

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js, fs

In my nodejs server, I would like to mock fs for my test with Mocha.
I end up using Mockery, but I really misunderstand a concept.

In my test (I use Typescript as well):

```
// mock for fs
var fsMock = {
  readdir: (path: string) => { return { err: undefined, files: [] } },
  writeFile: (path: string, content: string, encoding: string) => { return { err: undefined } },
  readFileSync: (path: string, encoding: string) => { return "lol" }
};
Mockery.registerMock('fs', fsMock);


beforeEach((done) => {
  Mockery.enable({
    useCleanCache: true,
    warnOnReplace: false,
    warnOnUnregistered: false
  });
}

afterEach(() => {
 Mockery.disable();
});
```

but unfortunately during my test, my module still use the old fs. I understood why is not working. Indeed, on my test, I:

- import my module at the top of the file
- as I import the module, my module will import its dependencies, as fs.
- as at this time mockery is not yet enabled (we are still not running a test...), the fs imported in my module is the original one
- I setup mockery before my test
- I execute my test, that fail because is still the original fs that is used...

Now the question is : how I can tell my module to re-require its dependencies to use my mocked version of fs ? And more globally, how I can mock fs easily ?

Thanks.

Comment: The trick is to require the module you are testing AFTER you have set up the mock.

Comment: Also, I think you have to enable Mockery first, before you register a mock

Comment: I use import and this can only be used at the top of the file :(

Comment: If you use Mockery, you have to use require. But I see you've found another solution, good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after testing and testing, I have ended up not using `mockery`, but `SinonJS` instead. It provides a very easy and effortless way to mock `fs`, e.g. :

```
import * as Fs from "fs"
import * as Sinon from "sinon"

// ..
// At a place inside a test where the mock is needed
Sinon.stub(Fs, "readdir").callsFake(
  (path: string, callback: Function) => { callback(null, ['toto']) }
);
```